# nmcli static routes are ignored

Tags: linux-networking, networkmanager

I'm in doubt about how NetworkManager through nmcli manages static routes. I have a CentOS 7.1.1503 server with three network interfaces:

```
[root@brick ~ ]# nmcli con show
NOMBRE         UUID                                  TIPO            DISPOSITIVO 
int-ofi-nueva  3646ca3f-42b7-4bef-a677-6f92a5d55ee7  802-3-ethernet  enp4s0      
tvcable-ext    e4dce451-6cc1-4a32-a8d6-394905f6a024  802-3-ethernet  enp2s0      
int-ofi-vieja  ecbb8828-cd46-4b18-8b5e-61291a051553  802-3-ethernet  enp5s0
```

Interface `enp2s0` is my WAN interface, and is the one with the default route. I have configured a static route through nmcli on interface `enp5s0`, but this route is not added to the routing table, even after I restart NetworkManager. Only routes corresponding to networks connected to each interface are added. Here are the details:

```
[root@brick ~ ]# ifconfig 
enp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  netmask 255.255.255.248  broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        inet6 fe80::feaa:14ff:fe76:fc7b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fc:aa:14:76:fc:7b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 13928182  bytes 1503741109 (1.4 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 372577  bytes 75107061 (71.6 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.2.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.17.2.255
        inet6 fe80::fe75:16ff:fe8a:a702  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fc:75:16:8a:a7:02  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 336962  bytes 70850425 (67.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 515100  bytes 589742232 (562.4 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp5s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.1.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.17.1.255
        inet6 fe80::c6e9:84ff:fe02:fbcc  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether c4:e9:84:02:fb:cc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 41353  bytes 12914987 (12.3 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 11386  bytes 1672601 (1.5 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Routing table:

```
[root@brick ~ ]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         <wan_gateway>   0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp2s0
172.17.1.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 enp5s0
172.17.2.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp4s0
<wan_network>   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 enp2s0
```

Connection Configuration:

```
[root@brick ~ ]# nmcli con show int-ofi-vieja 
connection.id:                          int-ofi-vieja
connection.uuid:                        ecbb8828-cd46-4b18-8b5e-61291a051553
connection.interface-name:              enp5s0
connection.type:                        802-3-ethernet
connection.autoconnect:                 yes
connection.autoconnect-priority:        0
connection.timestamp:                   1444951423
connection.read-only:                   no
connection.permissions:                 
connection.zone:                        --
connection.master:                      --
connection.slave-type:                  --
connection.secondaries:                 
connection.gateway-ping-timeout:        0
802-3-ethernet.port:                    --
802-3-ethernet.speed:                   0
802-3-ethernet.duplex:                  --
802-3-ethernet.auto-negotiate:          yes
802-3-ethernet.mac-address:             --
802-3-ethernet.cloned-mac-address:      --
802-3-ethernet.mac-address-blacklist:   
802-3-ethernet.mtu:                     auto
802-3-ethernet.s390-subchannels:        
802-3-ethernet.s390-nettype:            --
802-3-ethernet.s390-options:            
ipv4.method:                            manual
ipv4.dns:                               
ipv4.dns-search:                        
ipv4.addresses:                         172.17.1.2/24
ipv4.gateway:                           --
ipv4.routes:                            { ip = 10.125.25.0/24, nh = 172.17.1.9 }
ipv4.route-metric:                      1
ipv4.ignore-auto-routes:                no
ipv4.ignore-auto-dns:                   no
ipv4.dhcp-client-id:                    --
ipv4.dhcp-send-hostname:                yes
ipv4.dhcp-hostname:                     --
ipv4.never-default:                     no
ipv4.may-fail:                          yes
[ipv6 settings ommitted for brevity]
```

Notice that the property ipv4.routes is set, but the route is not loaded. Do I have to set something else on that connection to make the kernel see it?